# Consecutive SVG transforms with javascript not cumulative

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, scale

I fear I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how SVG transforms should behave when applied consecutively so would appreciate some help with the following. When I run the code below, I expect the circle to double in size each time I click Test, as well as moving along the axes. In fact, it doubles on the first click and then no more. Why does the transform not accumulate?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    svg,
    #containerId {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function test1() {
      myCircle.style.transform = "scale(2)";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="test1()">Test</button>
  </div>

  <div id="containerId">
    <svg>
                    <circle id="myCircle" cx="100" cy="100" r="20" fill="green"/>
                </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: for the same reason that x = 2 always results in x becoming 2. It's just an assignment.

Comment: You overwrite the scale, you don't add to it. Try using `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: See the examples for how to apply multiple transforms to an element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: My mistake was thinking that the transform is more like x = 2x since it establishes a new coordinate system and I assumed that the second iteration would take place on the new coordinates. += worked fine so thanks for the advice.

Comment: Concatenating strings is a bit inelegant. A better approach would be something like `scale *= 2; myCircle.style.transform = "scale("+scale+")";`